# Jtable not showing?

Tags: java, swing, awt

The Table won't show in the window.
Theres an outline, but no grid!
Please help!

tetris.java

```
package com.diesal11;

import com.diesal11.Board;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Tetris extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Tetris() {
        this.setSize(200, 400);
//      this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("Tetris");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Board board = new Board(this);
        JScrollPane ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(board);
        this.add(ScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tetris game = new Tetris();
        game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Board.java

```
package com.diesal11;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Board extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Tetris parent;
    int BoardWidth = 10;
    int BoardHeight = 20;
    JTable Table;

    public Board(Tetris parent){
//      setFocusable(true);
        this.parent = parent;
        this.Table = new JTable(this.BoardWidth, this.BoardHeight);
        this.Table.setValueAt("aaa", 0, 0);
        this.Table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        this.Table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("Test");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Im new to Java so Apologies if it's something really simple!

Comment: Perhaps a missing .setVisible(true) ? Haven't played with JTable in a while so I'm just throwing this as a comment since I'm not sure at all.

Comment: Thats in the first file in the "Main" method do i need to use it again on the JTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the table to the jpanel:

```
    ....
    this.Table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    this.Table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("Test");
    this.add(Table);
```

Also, the convention is to start variable names with lower case letter.

Comment: THANKYOU!
Ugh i feel like a noob, that was so simple!
Thanks for pointing out the variable naming stuff too!